# Can I use the NodeMCU ESP12 5v pin and control it with a relay?

Tags: relay, esp32

This question might be a little esoteric, but I cannot find any answer for it.

Situation:

I want to have more than 8 Analog sensors on a NodeMCU ESP32. Unfortunately due to SPECTACULARLY poor design choices you cannot do this and have WiFi active at the same time. This is a non-starter for my project so I need a workaround.

Thought:

What if I share the available pins I can use, by turning power on and off to the sensors in question? Easy enough using the digital GPIO's and just turning them on and off. The issue is that the sensors are at the end of long wires and so I need 5v power to ensure good readings. So what if I just use a relay, powered off the 5v pin on the ESP32, and switch them on and off?

My question is - can you even do this? Most of what I have seen would indicate I need a separate power supply for the relay itself, **and** the source being switched on and off, but I would like to avoid having another power supply, and build it as in the circuit diagram below.

A couple of notes:

- ignore the V1/1 V label in the picture - the circuit tool is very nice, but freezes a lot and I forgot to change that to VIN/5V before the screenshot
- I have also omitted the data connections from sensors and to the relays to switch them on and off - I know they need to exist, but they aren't the issue.
- I am running this project plugged in to the wall so source power is not an issue - I am not worried about drain or having a full 5V from the VIN pin

[image: Circuit diagram of two relays powered from the same 5v pin]

Before I fry parts, I thought it would be good to ask if anyone has tried this or if it is even possible?

Comment: your setup could work as described. sharing power isn't the issue. the main concern would be the 3.3v HIGH being high enough to actuate the relay module.

Comment: You dont really need relays, you could switch power on/off using a transistor, use the same power supply, there would be no issue.  However, you would need to find out if having two sensors connected to the same input would skew the results even if one is not powered. You are still introducing an "unknown" circuit and it could mean that your output changes or even damages the other circuit, as you are now apply a voltage to an output of another device.  You could use diodes to ensure current is only flowing out of the device and not into the other device, but again this will effect the voltage

Comment: dandavis the 3.3 *should* work to activate it (I can get a 3.3 model as well so that's an option too)

@ChadG - I had thought of the diodes to protect the data lines from the sensors, but the voltage drop could be an issue. Given the length of wire involved between sensor and MCU, we are talking about pretty small amounts (sub 3 volt most likely although not tested with a multi yet). Would the diode be that much of a drop in that case?

Comment: voltage drop over a diode is pretty fixed, so it actually becomes a much higher percentage with lower voltages. The exact amount changes based on the diode, but 0.7V is common.

Comment: Yeah dropping almost a full 1v is probably a no go for the readings from the sensor since they are analog and thus voltage dependent. Oh well, guess I am stuck then.

Comment: oh, @ChadG, thanks for the idea on the transistor instead of the relay. Probably a much more efficient design for the PCB, given it has to fit in roughly 70 x 70 MM!

Comment: Now you could use double throw relays between the output lines of sensors and the input on the uC.  This way only one was connected to it at a time, and the two sensor outputs would not be connected this way.

Comment: Another option, and probably the cleanest, is to use adc IC's.  The ones I link are only a single channel, but they communicator over I2C so you can use a number of them off the same bus, now you actually have as many inputs as you need   https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Analog-Devices/5962-9475501MPA?qs=sGAEpiMZZMvTvDTV69d2QgYdPJm2vkaBTxTWToXHJa8%3D

Comment: Just get an additional power supply that is capable of providing enough current. The relay-approach is much too complicate and will be more expensive than an ordinary PSU...

Comment: @SimSon the relays were not being considered because of power draw, but so that the sensors could be multiplexed to the inputs.(have one set on at a time)

Comment: @ChadG Doesn't the esp32 have enough pins that are multiplexed to the ADC internally? And if the OP really needs more pins than available then using an analog multiplexer IC would be the way to go in my opinion...

Comment: I am liking the ADC IC idea. It would eliminate both the power and " not enough pins" issue. I think it will fit in the confines of the PCB - just need to see. I have several on the bench, but it never occurred to me to go that route. DUH.